# Why is Designer 2010 not adding my web part to the zone?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, visual-web-part

I'm currently working on a SharePoint 2010 site, and I've been using both Designer 2010 and Visual Studio 2010 to create Web Parts for the pages.

One of the Web Parts I created in VS 2010 was built and deployed successfully, and Designer 2010 shows it in the list of custom Web Parts, yet Designer 2010 won't add it to the Web Part Zone. There is no error in the logs about the Web Part and I'm quite stumped.

Is there a way to fix this, so the Web Part will show up in the Zone on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Start debugging by checking Webpart hidden property. [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.hidden.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), If it's hidden by default enable it.